# How to remove "Show row weights" option on File Upload field?

Tags: 7, files

I have created a file field with multiple uploads allowed. Is there any way(except CSS) I can remove "Show row weights" link from file upload field? Or is there any way to remove weight drop down entirely from file field?

Comment: It is possible bot sure that the whole thing work. try `hook_form_alter`

Comment: Do you mean the extra top-right button with the four arrows so you can change the weight by integers? From a usability and cross-platform point-of-view, you should never remove that functionality, since it's the alternative for when you've got JS disabled or is not working as expected.

Comment: My issue is that I want the extra top right button as it is but just want to remove the link. I have done is using locale module for now. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I found a great article that explains how to do this in a way you can indicate to which fields apply it. enjoy it!
https://www.commercialprogression.com/post/how-remove-tabledrag-rearranging-multiple-value-field-widgets

Comment: Double up! All one has to do is pasting the code inside a .module, adding an .info and insert a field name within the last function. Put it on github here: https://github.com/leymannx/drupal-disable-weight-on-multi-value-fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable/alter `settings.tableDrag` function.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  unset($javascript['misc/tabledrag.js']);
}
?>
```

Comment: This removes the "Show row weights" link but when enabled it displays the Weight column.  It's a good answer but a complete solution would include removal of the Weight column.

Comment: This will remove the ability to reorder the rows entirely, not just remove the link at the top of the page. Adding this code will break the ability to order items. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.

Answer (score 6):

The first part of your question is regarding removal of link "Show row weights" (or "Hide row weights" if dragging functionality is disabled) in a form where table rows are draggable, so I'm going to answer that.

"Show row weights" string appears in `Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.showColumns()` method and "Hide row weights" appers in `Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.hideColumns()` method that is included in `tabledrag.js` file (see [head in Drupal 7.x branch](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x:/misc/tabledrag.js)) so you need to override these methods in order to replace or remove these strings without losing row dragging functionality.

Place this code in a .js file that is loaded along with the form that uses tabledrag.js:

```
(function ($) {
  // Copy hideColumns() method
  var hideColumns = Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.hideColumns;
  Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.hideColumns = function() {
    // Call the original hideColumns() method
    hideColumns.call(this);
    // Remove the 'Show row weights' string
    $('.tabledrag-toggle-weight').text('');
  }

  // Copy showColumns() method
  var showColumns = Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.showColumns;
  Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.showColumns = function () {
    // Call the original showColumns() method
    showColumns.call(this);
    // Remove the 'Hide row weights' string
    $('.tabledrag-toggle-weight').text('');
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: will it any effect on default misc/tabledrag.js ?

Comment: @Fawwad, the only side effect of the provided code is that toggle element text is hidden. Default `hideColumns()` and `showColumns()` methods are still invoked.

Comment: It works but it's much easier to simply add to your css: .tabledrag-toggle-weight-wrapper,
.tabledrag-toggle-weight,
.tableresponsive-toggle-columns,
.tableresponsive-toggle {
  height: 0 !important;
  font-size: 0 !important;
  color: transparent !important;
  display: none !important;
}
Yes, it seems a bit overkill but, depending on various themes, some might not be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for Drupal 8 using `hook_preprocess_field_multiple_value_form()`

First find the field you want to remove re-ordering ability from:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field_multiple_value_form().
 */
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_field_multiple_value_form(&$variables) {
  if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'MY_FIELD_NAME') {
    MY_MODULE_remove_table_reordering($variables['table']);
  }
}
```

And then call a helper function to actually remove the tables re-ordering functionality:

```
/**
 * Removes the ability for a table to be re-ordered.
 */
function MY_MODULE_remove_table_reordering(&$table) {
  unset($table['#tabledrag']);

  // Remove re-order header column
  foreach($table['#header'] as $header_i => $header) {
    if(is_object($header) && (string) $header == 'Order') {
      unset($table['#header'][$header_i]);
    }
  }

  // Loop table rows
  foreach($table['#rows'] as &$row) {

    // Remove draggable class from tr
    $i = array_search('draggable', $row['class']);
    if($i !== FALSE) {
      unset($row['class'][$i]);
    }

    // Loop columns in row
    foreach($row['data'] as $col_i => &$col) {

      if(empty($col['class'])) {
        continue;
      }

      // Remove td with drag handle
      $i = array_search('field-multiple-drag', $col['class']);
      if($i !== FALSE) {
        unset($row['data'][$col_i]);
      }

      // Remove td with re-ordering select
      $i = array_search('delta-order', $col['class']);
      if($i !== FALSE) {
        unset($row['data'][$col_i]);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try a theme-override, as in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.form.inc/function/theme_field_multiple_value_form/7

Paste the function to your theme's template.php, rename 'theme_' in the function name to your theme's name and clear the cache.

Find the line saying

```
drupal_add_tabledrag($table_id, 'order', 'sibling', $order_class);
```

and comment it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about disabling for a single field, but I found myself wanting to disable the row dragging for an entire form.

monymirza suggested an answer to disable it entirely. However in D7, that approach is not reliable, because in some forms drupal_add_tabledrag() will be called after your hook_js_alter().  This is typical Drupal - everything is theoretically customizable, but in practice it's error prone and sensitive.

In the end I used the following hook_form_alter() to disable table drag for just one specific form:

```
<?php

/**                                                                                                                                
 * Implements hook_form_alter()                                                                                                    
 */                                                                                                                                
function sunflower_custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'field_ui_field_overview_form' && $form['#bundle'] == 'sunflower_habitat') {
    // The habitat form is wizardized based on row weights.  This is a sensitive thing, and drupal's row weight javascript is not at all sensitive, completely changing all values when it feels like it.  So we don't want that "feature" on this form.             

    // Disable it, if already enabled.                                                                                             
    $javascript = &drupal_static('drupal_add_js', array());
    unset($javascript['misc/tabledrag.js']);

    // Prevent it from being enabled later.                                                                                        
    $tabledrag_added = &drupal_static('drupal_add_tabledrag');
    $tabledrag_added = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to moneymirza's answer to remove the weights and add a qualifyer, since we don't want to disable `tabledrag.js` from the entire site.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  // Use a more specific page condition as desired.
  if(arg(0) == "node" && arg(2) == "edit") {
    unset($javascript['misc/tabledrag.js']);
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/MODULENAME.js');
  }
}
```

Then make a MODULENAME.js file:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.NoTabledragWeights = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // Again, get more specific if desired.
      $('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```