# How can I remove "Show row weights" as well as the weight column in D7?

Tags: 7, forms

[This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/62795/45555) shows how to remove the "Show row weights" text from a form. However, as the comment to this answer suggests, it doesn't remove the weight column as well.

How can I update the following code to also remove the weight column from my form?

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  unset($javascript['misc/tabledrag.js']);
}
?>
```

Or, is there a better way to do this? This seems like a hacked way of removing the row weights.

Comment: You could simply hide both elements with CSS.

Comment: @Jeroen is that actually the right way to do this? I'm not a Drupal expert but in most frameworks I know that would be a hacked fix...although using this javascript `unset` is a hack also...

Comment: I think it depends on why you want to hide it. Is it because you don't need the functionality or is it because you certainly don't want your users to use it? In the first case, I personally don't mind using CSS: why making things complicated when there's an easy solution?

Comment: @Jeroen it's that the functionality confuses users who don't know what a "row weight" is. I guess it's OK to hide via CSS.

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove it? You know that without it you can't reorder == change weights? Is locking element order your desired result? Or you simply want to make sure it stays hidden?

Comment: @Mołot It's a form that my end-users are filling in so they don't need/want to change the order of questions. It seems weird that this is an option for end-users, is there another way to make forms for end-users in Drupal? I've never seen a form online that lets end users reorder the questions...it seems ridiculous that it's not just an admin feature.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to display those elements because it confuses users, you could simply hide them with CSS. Use Firebug or something alike to determine the correct classes in order to adapt the code underneath.

```
#YOUR-FORM-ID .tabledrag-toggle-weight-wrapper,
#YOUR-FORM-ID .field-multiple-drag {
  display: none;
}
```